# Marionette - combining CollectionView with View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm new to marionette and I would like to generate CollectionView inside a CollectionView.
I read that if a view gets collection as argument it stores it as 'items' argunemt. My problem boils down to this:

```
const { View, CollectionView } = Marionette; 

const collection = new Backbone.Collection([
    {name: 'Marionette.js'}, {name: 'Backbone.js'}
]);

const MyView = View.extend({
    el: 'body',
  template: _.template(`
  <ul>
    <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
    <li><%- item.name %></li>
    <% }) %>
  </ul>
  `)
});

const MyCollectionView = CollectionView.extend({
    childView: MyView
})


const myCollectionView = new MyCollectionView([{collection: collection}]);
myCollectionView.render();
```

But it does not work. Can you guys help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer!
It needs only to add

```
childViewOptions(model) {
    return {collection: model.get('collection')};
},
```

into MyCollectionView and change ...(items,... to be named collection and it does exactly what I wanted.